# Proofing the sum of the squre cosines of the angle between a vector and the vectors of the base.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

I'm having trouble getting this proof right, its somthing like this

Let $ \{e_1, e_2, ... e_n \}$ be an orthonormal basis, of a vector space with internal product $\mathbb V$, and $\theta_i$, the angle between $e_i$ and $v\neq 0 \in \mathbb V$, then:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\cos^{2}{\theta_i}=1$

In general I'm trying to proof it, for a dot product, in a space $\mathbb R^n$...
i have try using the expansion theorem, point product definition, but i can't find it right!

I have this

$\cos{\theta_i}= \frac{\langle e_i,v\rangle}{||v||}  $

writing $v$ in terms of the basis we get (using the expansion theorem)

$v=\sum_{i=0}^{n}=\frac{\langle v,e_i \rangle}{||e_i||^2}e_i$, where $||e_i||=1$

(not sure if the theorem its call like that, but at least in Hoffman's Linear algebra book spanish version, and Claudio Pita's that is how the call the theorem)
i have checked in a lot of books, and I'm not entirely sure that I've approached the problem the right way, any suggestions?

Comment: One way to prove it is to write $\vec v$ as $\Sigma (\vec v \cdot \hat e_i)\hat e_i$ and then calculate  $\vec v \cdot \vec v$.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to showing what you want. I think what you are missing is that $\|\mathbf{v}\|^{2}= \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{v} \rangle$.

Given any orthonormal basis $\lbrace \mathbf{e}_{1}, \dots, \mathbf{e}_{n}\rbrace$, you can decompose $\mathbf{v}$ as follows:
$$
\mathbf{v}
= 
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{e}_{i}\rangle}{\|\mathbf{e}_{i}\|} \mathbf{e}_{i}
=
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{e}_{i}\rangle \mathbf{e}_{i}. \quad (1)
$$
Now, you have
$$
\|\mathbf{v}\|^{2}= \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{v} \rangle
= 
\langle \mathbf{v}, \sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{e}_{i}\rangle \mathbf{e}_{i} \rangle
= 
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{e}_{i}\rangle^{2}. \quad (2)
$$
Dividing both sides by $\|\mathbf{v}\|^{2}$, you get your desired result.

Comment: The thing is got to that result but, i cant really see how that helps on the cosine proof, that is the main problem... i think i'm all most there but its unclear

Comment: You have written that $\cos{\theta_{i}} = \frac{\langle\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{e}_{i}\rangle}{\|\mathbf{v}\|}$. In equation (2), if you divide both sides by $\|\mathbf{v}\|^{2}$, then you get $1 = \dots$

Comment: I knew! i wasn't seeing something! thanks.